# Query with date comparision on Android with Room

Tags: android, sqlite, date, android-room

I want to query my db with a date comparision with current Date.

Here is my query :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User INNER JOIN AutoLogin ON User.user_Id = AutoLogin.user_Id AND AutoLogin.token_Id = :autoLoginToken AND Autologin.expiration_date > date('now')")
Single<User> getUserByAutoLogin(String autoLoginToken);
```

Here is my AutoLogin class :

```
public class AutoLogin implements Parcelable {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "token_Id")
    private String tokenId;
    @NonNull
    @TypeConverters(DataTypeConverter.class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "expiration_date")
    private Date expirationDate;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_Id")
    private Long userId;
```

My converters :

```
    @androidx.room.TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long value) {
        return value == null ? null : new Date(value);
    }

    @androidx.room.TypeConverter
    public static Long toLong(Date value) {
        return value == null ? null : value.getTime();
    }
```

The query doesn't work and retrieve no result. I feel this is a problem with the date part of the it. Anybody see what's my error ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 5 functions which SQLite provides:

1. **date(...)** returns just the date.
2. **time(...)** returns just the time.
3. **datetime(...)** returns both the date and time.
4. **julianday(...)** returns the Julian Day.
5. **strftime(...)** returns a value formatted with your given format
   string. The first four can be thought of as variations of strftime
   with a pre-defined format.

For more information read the blog

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-time-2b4cf9672b98

Answer (score 1):

You not do same compare with  `Autologin.expiration_date > date('now')"`

`expiration_date` be like **1579550175468** `date('now')` be like **2020-01-20**

To compare same and want to do by date and no time you can use

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User INNER JOIN AutoLogin ON " +
        "User.user_Id = AutoLogin.user_Id " +
        "AND AutoLogin.token_Id = :autoLoginToken " +
        "AND date(Autologin.expiration_date / 1000,'unixepoch') > date('now')")
```

Other Answer say

> ```
> @Query("SELECT * FROM User INNER JOIN AutoLogin ON User.user_Id = AutoLogin.user_Id AND AutoLogin.token_Id = :autoLoginToken AND Autologin.expiration_date > strftime('%s', 'now')")
> ```

not work well do compare **1579550175468** with **1579551916** it not do `/ 1000`, if it do, it have time to second

Answer (score 0):

Since you used [Date.getTime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) method in your `TypeConverter` class, the value stored in DB will be [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

> long getTime() 
> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

So in your query, you must compare `expiration_date` column value with current Unix time. Based on [SQLite official website](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), you can get current Unix time by `strftime('%s', 'now')` expression. Your query should be like below:

```java
@Query("SELECT * FROM User INNER JOIN AutoLogin ON User.user_Id = AutoLogin.user_Id AND AutoLogin.token_Id = :autoLoginToken AND Autologin.expiration_date > (strftime('%s', 'now') * 1000)")
Single<User> getUserByAutoLogin(String autoLoginToken);
```